# WSO2 Maven2 Repository contains outdated org.wso2.carbon.registry.core-4.2.0 artifact

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I need to rebuild some artifacts for **APIM 1.7.0**: `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl` and `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway` and compilation fails bacause `org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.pagination.PaginationContext` does not contain `getLength()` method.

This class `PaginationContext` comes from **org.wso2.carbon.registry.core-4.2.0** dependency downloaded from [wso2-maven2-repository](http://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/).

I took a look at `Bnd-LastModified` timestamps from MANIFEST.MF for both artifacts from APIM distribution and from wso2-maven2-repository and noticed strange thing: artifact from wso2-maven2-repository was built earlear then one from distribution.

Look:

> **from wso2-maven2-repository**: 1378306607534 (Wed, 04 Sep 2013 14:56:47 GMT)
>
> **from distribution**: 1400854868301 (Fri, 23 May 2014 14:21:08 GMT)

So the question is: dear WSO2 team, could you please update artifact in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with the repository, but this is how it is done. When a product is released, Carbon kernel sometimes has to be patched. So those patched components are issued separately as patch000x. (patch [sources available here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/).) Now if we look at the WSO2 [release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/), APIM 1.7 is released in chunk-11 and there have been 8 kernel patches released prior to that. So what you have to do is, checkout the kernel patches sources [from here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/) and build each from patch0001 to patch0008 in that order. Then those updated jars will be there in your m2 repo.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev! Actually didn't notice patches sources